# recover all line from an attribute in a database in json

Tags: python, json, database

To simplify my problem,  I have a base in json, and I recover all of my lines of json to put informations in a base.
It seems easy for moments,  but problem is that my json is not correctly written

So i did a code to recover all my json lines,  but it doesn't work on all lines, like "biographie".

I show you

```
{"name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "personal_name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:00:41.270799"}, "key": "/authors/OL1001461A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "personal_name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:00:41.270799"}, "key": "/authors/OL1001461A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
```

you see, you have name,personal name ...

sometimes you have other informations,

```
{"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen's Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster's _Men at the Bar_][1]rnrnrn  rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""}, "name": "William Pinder Eversley", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1918", "photos": [6897255, 6897254], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"}, "latest_revision": 6, "key": "/authors/OL1003081A", "birth_date": "1851", "personal_name": "William Pinder Eversley", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 6}


{"name": "Valerie Meyer", "personal_name": "Valerie Meyer", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:22:33.63997"}, "key": "/authors/OL1004062A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
```

You can see i have a lot of problem with the element "bio":  because he is not written correctely at all,  the quota are not interpreted correctely and "<"  too  so I got this code to change the structure of bio to exploit it.

Here my code to change structure of bio

```py
import re
import json
import pprint


bio_regex = re.compile(
    r"""
("bio":\s*{)   # bio field start
(.*?)          # content
(},)           # bio field end
(?=\s*(?:"\w+"|}))  # followed by another one or the json end
""",
    flags=re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)

value_regex = re.compile(
    r"""
("value":\s*")   # value field start
(.*?)            # content
("\s*\Z)         # value field end + end of string
""",
    flags=re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)


def normalize_value(mo):
    start, content, end = mo.group(1, 2, 3)
    content = content.replace('"', '\\"')
    return start + content + end


def normalize_bio(mo):
    start, content, end = mo.group(1, 2, 3)
    content = value_regex.sub(normalize_value, content)
    return start + content + end

messy_json = """
{ 
  "bio":{ 
    "type":"/type/text",
    "value":"> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen's Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster's Men at the Bar][1]rnrnrn rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""
  },
  "name":"William Pinder Eversley",
  "created":{ 
    "type":"/type/datetime",
    "value":"2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"
  },
  "death_date":"1918",
  "photos":[ 
    6897255,
    6897254
  ],
  "last_modified":{ 
    "type":"/type/datetime",
    "value":"2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"
  },
  "latest_revision":6,
  "key":"/authors/OL1003081A",
  "birth_date":"1851",
  "personal_name":"William Pinder Eversley",
  "type":{ 
    "key":"/type/author"
  },
  "revision":6
}"""


result = bio_regex.sub(normalize_bio, messy_json)
obj = json.loads(result)
```

Here is the result:

```
{'bio': {'type': '/type/text',
         'value': '> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen\'s Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the '
                  "South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of "
                  'the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest '
                  "son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench "
                  'Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster\'s Men at the Bar][1]rnrnrn rnrn[1]: '
                  'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar"'},
 'birth_date': '1851',
 'created': {'type': '/type/datetime', 'value': '2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462'},
 'death_date': '1918',
 'key': '/authors/OL1003081A',
 'last_modified': {'type': '/type/datetime', 'value': '2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159'},
 'latest_revision': 6,
 'name': 'William Pinder Eversley',
 'personal_name': 'William Pinder Eversley',
 'photos': [6897255, 6897254],
 'revision': 6,
 'type': {'key': '/type/author'}}
```

The problem here is that this script is good if I put my entire line in my code,  but i would like to recover my 1000000 lines of bio with the good structure,  I can't do that 1 per 1,  I tried a lot of thing with a loop to recover 1 per 1 but it puts me always an error,  I need know how recuperate it witch a loop  .
I need upgrade my code to take all lines of database from line bio and not only 1 per 1

Thanks in advance and thanks to listen me!

Comment: Another approach to make it a valid `json`: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OrganicRosySet)

Comment: ty for your answer,  I checked it and it works,  but problem is how can I put a lot of line  of "bio",  in your example, you have only bio:{  ....}   But i would like know How Can i open my json file  ( for exemple  openlibraryjson.json)  and take only line who begin per bio:{....}  to modify all of them and treat all of my database !   Say me if I need post other thing to clarify !! Thanks you very much man for your help !!!

Comment: ***"take only line who begin per `bio: {}`"***: My approach should work with any size of `json` file. Read your whole `json` file into memory using `open(<json file>): data = fh.read()`

Answer (score 0):

For exemple, I wanted say that : I have a file ,  openlibraryjson.json :

with these lines :

`{"name": "Ismail Ibrahim Dr.", "title": "Dr.", "personal_name": "Ismail Ibrahim", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "key": "/authors/OL100304A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 1}
{"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen's Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster's Men at the Bar][1]rnrnrn  rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""}, "name": "William Pinder Eversley", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1918", "photos": [6897255, 6897254], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"}, "latest_revision": 6, "key": "/authors/OL1003081A", "birth_date": "1851", "personal_name": "William Pinder Eversley", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 6}
{"name": "Valerie Meyer", "personal_name": "Valerie Meyer", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:22:33.63997"}, "key": "/authors/OL1004062A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "[Deutsch] Deutscher Orientalist und Theologe.rn[English] German orientalist and biblical scholar."}, "name": "August Dillmann", "links": [{"url": "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Dillmann", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Wikipedia (Deutsch)"}, {"url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Dillmann", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Wikipedia (English)"}], "personal_name": "August Dillmann", "death_date": "4 July 1894.", "alternate_names": ["Christian Friedrich August Dillmann", "Ch. F. A. Dillmann", "Friedrich August Dillmann", "F. A. Dillmann", "Augustus Dillmann", "August Dillmann", "A. Dillmann"], "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "photos": [6676274], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2017-03-31T12:45:57.925108"}, "latest_revision": 8, "key": "/authors/OL1179559A", "birth_date": "25 April 1823", "revision": 8, "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "remote_ids": {"viaf": "45046685", "wikidata": "Q75216"}}
{"last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "name": "Physikertagung (1966 Munich, Germany)", "key": "/authors/OL1179696A", "revision": 1}`

I would like take only line bio and treat them to put them functionnal,  for it I tried to open my file, and I Treat name,personal_name ... with a loop,  it works but not for bio because it's not written correctly,  so I skip bio in my script for moment  But now i would like to don't skip bio and work with bio in the same way that for name,personal_name ...

Like it  :

`with open('openlibrary(3).json') as file:
    for i in range(101):
        line = file.readline()
        if "bio" in line:
            line.replace("\'", "’")
            continue
        content_json = json.loads(line)
        if not "personal_name" in line:
           #print('NULL')
           ligne.append("NULL")
           continue
        try:
            #print(content_json['name'])
            ligne.append(content_json['personal_name'])
        except IndexError:
            print('NULL')
        if not "personal_name" in line:
            # print('NULL')
            personal_nom.append("NULL")
            continue
        try:
            # print(content_json['name'])
            personal_nom.append(content_json['personal_name'])
        except IndexError:
            print('NULL')`

I just put some code here to show a bit what i did for name,personal_name...

Thanks you again for listen me and aswer me !!!!